# Center background image in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, background, position

does anyone know how to center image on page in internet explorer? I use this, but it didn´t work

```
body{

margin:0;
padding:0;

font-family:"Arial", Times, serif;
font-size:10px;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-image:url('background.png') center    top;
background-position:center top;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-color:#cfddef ;

}
```

this didn´t work too

```
body{

margin:0;
padding:0;

font-family:"Arial", Times, serif;
font-size:10px;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background: #cfddef url("background.png") no-repeat center top;

}
```

thanks for answer :)

Comment: That should work...we need to see it in action. Please create a JSFiddle. Note `background-image:url('background.png') center top;` should just be `background-image:url('background.png');`

Comment: Is there a specific version of IE you are having issues with?

Comment: Your repeating yourself. Try the shorthand version background: #cfddef url("background.png") no-repeat center top;

Comment: my site is http://velvetart.net, but it will work when your screen resolution is 1366x768px, because the background image has same width

Comment: Like @Paulie_D says is only the `center top` in the sentence of `background-image`

Comment: Or make it just one line see this http://jsfiddle.net/tjQLG/4/

Comment: Works fine in IE10 on W8

Comment: one line code work in google chrome, but i can´t open jsfiddle in explorer :/ but my background work in google chrome too, just not in explorer

Comment: Your site displays quite a lot of content op top of the background image, so the background image is hardly visible! If you were to remove all the content, leaving only the CSS styles, you would see that it would work. Oh, and the main graphic on top, [this one](http://velvetart.net/wp-content/themes/LilyCollinsVA/images/header.png), looks very much like the background image, [this one](http://velvetart.net/wp-content/themes/LilyCollinsVA/images/background.png), so that may cause confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kvkmv/). Is this what you are looking for?

```
body{
margin:0;
padding:0;

font-family:"Arial", Times, serif;
font-size:10px;
width:100%;
height:100%;


background-image:url('http://storage3d.com/storage/2007.02/2aae1d60e516d24a40230e01ee33a00f.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center;
    background-attachment:fixed;


background-color:#cfddef ;

}
```